# Blender renders circles instead of squares

Tags: rendering

Hi and thanks for any help that I can get in advance.

I'm rendering my first file and for some reason blender is rendering squares as circles. Please help!

What I'm trying to render:
[image: 3D View]

What's being rendered:
[image: Render View Result]

Comment: Didn't know how to look for the problem! Sorry and thanks!

Comment: No problem, your question still holds a [value as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/). Welcome to Blender.se

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn Off Subsurface Modifier completely.

Comment: @AlfonsoMello Please mark as answer. Or Downvote.